# Posting file upload to ec2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload files from my website to an amazon ec2 instance, i am using the IP Address; however, the connection is timing out. I have the private key, but am not using it in any way, so far.

what do I need to do to keep this from timing out, and successfully upload my items/overwrite old items (with the same name), and where should the code be added, i am assuming for the private key...?

I have attempted specifying the folder, using http instead of https, updating my server

onclick handler

```
onClickHandler = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post("https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/upload", data, {
       // receive two    parameter endpoint url ,form data
   }).then(res => { // then print response status
    console.log(res.statusText)
 })
};
```

Server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, 'public/upload')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, file.originalname )
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

app.post('/upload',function(req, res) {

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
         if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
             return res.status(500).json(err)
         } else if (err) {
             return res.status(500).json(err)
         }
    return res.status(200).send(req.file)

  })

});


app.listen(8000, function() {

  console.log('App running on port 8000');

});
```

i need help figuring out what i am missing, and where to put it, Thank you to anyone who is able to help me out!